# After Placing a button i cant move the shape using the arrow keys

Tags: c#, winforms

This is a sample code that is part of a bigger piece of code, i want to use this code to move a picture box but when buttons are introduced in the form i cant move it after, i have tried many fixes on the internet but nothing works like the `this.KeyPreview = true;` fix but nothing seems to work.

```
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Right
                && (pictureBox1.Location.X + pictureBox1.Width) < this.Width)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 15,
                    pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 15,
                    pictureBox1.Location.Y);
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X,
                    pictureBox1.Location.Y - 15);
            }
            else if (e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X,
                    pictureBox1.Location.Y + 15);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.KeyPreview = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly happens after selecting the button and you use the down button

Comment: if a button exists in a form, then the arrow keys are not working, even before clicking the button. By the time it exists i cant use arrow keys, also it is highlighted automatically before clicking it

Comment: i still have a hard time understanding what you tryt to do when runninf the programm you arent't allowed to change the position manually, your code on the other hand capture all keys pressed and thry to change the picture box position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you are correct that as soon as there is a focused button on the form, it will monopolize Key messages and `Form1_KeyDown` will no longer be called or move the picture box as you have observed.

The way around this is to implement [IMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter?view=windowsdesktop-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) so that we can choose to intercept **Win32** [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message unconditionally. Try something like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            var e = new KeyEventArgs(((Keys)m.WParam) | Control.ModifierKeys);
            OnHotKeyPreview(FromHandle(m.HWnd), e);
            return (e.Handled);
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void OnHotKeyPreview(Control? control, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Left: onMoveLeft(); e.Handled = true; break;
            case Keys.Up: onMoveUp(); e.Handled = true; break;
            case Keys.Right:  onMoveRight(); e.Handled = true; break;
            case Keys.Down: onMoveDown(); e.Handled = true; break;
        }
    }
    private void onMoveLeft() =>
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 15, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
    private void onMoveUp() => 
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - 15);
    private void onMoveRight() =>
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 15,
            pictureBox1.Location.Y);
    private void onMoveDown() =>
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 15);
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
}
```

---

**Alternative**

The cleaner approach, however, would be to inherit from `PictureBox` and implement the `IMessageFilter` *there*, to make an extended `PictureBoxEx` control that knows how to move *itself* by handling the intercepted key events.

[image: move either picture boxe]

To use this control, go to the Designer.cs file and swap out instances of `PictureBox` for extended class `PictureBoxEx`. Here's the final, alternative solution with the `Form` class simplified as a result. The scheme here is to set the border of the picture box(es) to move.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonDeselect.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var pb in Controls.OfType<PictureBoxEx>())
            {
                pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**PictureBoxEx**

```
class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox, IMessageFilter
{
    public PictureBoxEx()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
        Disposed += (sender, e) => Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        if (ModifierKeys != Keys.Control)   // Allow multiple select.
        {
            foreach (var pb in Parent.Controls.OfType<PictureBoxEx>())
            {
                pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            }
        }
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if ((m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) && (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.FixedSingle))
        {

            var e = new KeyEventArgs(((Keys)m.WParam) | Control.ModifierKeys);
            OnKeyDown(e);
            return (e.Handled);
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
                Location = new Point(Location.X - 15, Location.Y);
                break;
            case Keys.Up:
                Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y - 15);
                break;
            case Keys.Right:
                Location = new Point(Location.X + 15, Location.Y);
                break;
            case Keys.Down:
                Location = new Point(Location.X, Location.Y + 15);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/arrow-keys-move-button.git)