# Why does the rectangle not move when i press D?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So i am trying to make a paint like program for a project at uni and i have to make shapes move.Our professor advised that we use KeyDown but for some reason i cant figure out why it wont move.Code is below

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    bool isMouseDown = false;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Width = 900;
        this.Height = 700;
        bm = new Bitmap(pic.Width, pic.Height);
        bm2 = new Bitmap(pic2.Width, pic2.Height);
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bm);
        g2 = Graphics.FromImage(bm2);
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        pic.Image = bm;
        pic2.Image = bm2;
        pic.Parent = pic2;
        pic.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        pic2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    Bitmap bm, bm2;
    Graphics g, g2;
    bool paint = false;
    Point px, py;
    private Point MouseDownLocation;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    int index;
    Pen erase = new Pen(Color.Transparent, 10);
    int x, y, sX, sY, cX, cY;

    ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
    Color new_color;

 private void pic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
     paint = true;
     MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
     py = e.Location;
     px = e.Location;

     cX = e.X;
     cY = e.Y;

     sX = e.X;
     sY = e.Y;
 }

private void pic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (paint)
    {
        if (index == 1)
        {
            px = e.Location;
            g.DrawLine(p, px, py);
            py = px;
        }
        if (index == 2)
        {
            px = e.Location;
            g.DrawLine(erase, px, py);
            py = px;
        }
    }
    pic.Refresh();

    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
    sX = e.X - cX;
    sY = e.Y - cY;
}

private void pic_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    isMouseDown = false;
    paint = false;

    sX = x - cX;
    sY = y - cY;

    if (index == 3)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(p, cX, cY, sX, sY);
    }
    if (index == 4)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(cX, cY, sX, sY);
        g.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
    }
    if (index == 5)
    {
        g.DrawLine(p, cX, cY, x, y);
    }

}

private void pic_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    if (paint)
    {
        if (index == 3)
        {
            g.DrawEllipse(p, cX, cY, sX, sY);
        }
        if (index == 4)
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(p, rect);
        }
        if (index == 5)
        {
            g.DrawLine(p, cX, cY, x, y);
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.D)
    {
        rect.X += 10;
        
    }
}
```

I tried moving it with the Form1_KeyDown function but i cant figure it out or find any online source that helps.

Comment: This answer explains why `Form1_KeyDown` probably won't work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77471501/5438626

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After Placing a button i cant move the shape using the arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471136/after-placing-a-button-i-cant-move-the-shape-using-the-arrow-keys)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would put a breakpoint in Form1_KeyDown to verify that the code gets executed when you press a key. Alternatively you could put a Debug.Writeline() call there and watch the output window while typing.

The reason why you don't see your rectangle move is probably that pic_Paint doesn't get called after you changed your rectangle. To achieve that you should call Invalidate() after you changed the position to invoke a redraw of your form.